# Compile error : fatal error: 'boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp' file not found

Tags: c++, boost

These are the header files and libraries

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <strings.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <dirent.h>


#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/c_array.hpp>


#include "mail.h"
```

I am trying to compile this c++ file I got using

```
g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -o evaluate_object evaluate_object.cpp
```

The compile output

```
evaluate_object.cpp:13:10: fatal error: 'boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp' file
      not found
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Ps: I run on macos sierra 10.12
I have tried install boost by these ways:

- sudo port install boost
- brew install boost
- sudo port install boost +universal

But I still got the same problem.
I would be happy to get out of this noob zone. 
I am a macos newbie too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your "boost" includes directory is not present within environment defined include directories. You might want to specify one by passing "-I" argument to g++ command, i.e.

> g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/blahblah -o evaluate_object evaluate_object.cpp

Also your code is incomplete and perhaps if you actually call some of the boost functions you might need to add some objects for linking and then you will face "undefined reference to" error. To overcome such you need to specify "-L" flag for your g++ command.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the -l flag does, but I tried running your suggested command.

g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -l/usr/local/Cellar/boost -o evaluate_object evaluate_object.cpp

I still got the same output error. And regarding code, it's quite too long. It's not my code though

Comment: -I flag points to the directories where the compiler would look for header files which you #include in your code. Please check if the mentioned is physically present on your drive, if it's not probably your boost installation does not include uBLAS.

Comment: I have checked the directory below : /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.0/include/boost/numeric/ublas . 

Both boost and uBLAS are physically found as you can see. What should I do now ?

Comment: Ok, now I see you've specified incorrect directory to the -I argument, it should be: `-I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.0/include`